# How to create google image slideshow using python

Tags: python, image, slider, slideshow

I am trying to build the image slide show using python.
S0, I am trying deferent way but I, not get success.

I am trying to build the google images slideshow using python.
Then I do not want to download and store the images in local images I want to get images URL and show in the slide show.

I am trying to use this code. Please help me to build this. I am using python 3 in windows 10 OS

```
import time
import csv
from webdriverplus import WebDriver
from itertools import *

csvfile = input("Enter the name of the csv input file . . .")
loopcall = input("Infinite loop? (yes/no) . . .")
delay = input("Time delay for each URL visit (in seconds) . . . ")
delay = int(delay)

urls = csv.reader(open(csvfile, "rU"))

if loopcall == "yes":

    for url in cycle(urls):

        browser = WebDriver('firefox', reuse_browser=True)

        browser.maximize_window()

        browser.get(url[0])

        time.sleep(delay)

elif loopcall == "no":

    for url in urls:

        browser = WebDriver('firefox', reuse_browser=True)

        browser.maximize_window()

        browser.get(url[0])

        time.sleep(delay)

        browser.quit()

else:

    print ("Please enter yes or no to specify the loop . . . ")
```

this is my img.csv file

```
https://www.carzonelanka.lk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/audi-homepage.png
https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/SONATA-hero-option1-764A5360-edit-640x354.jpg
https://www.vega.lk/img/evx/Ws4.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This part here is the problematic part:

```py
delay = input("Time delay for each URL visit (in seconds) . . . ")
delay = int(delay)
```

Change it to:

```py
delay = int(input("Time delay for each URL visit (in seconds) . . . "))
```

Comment: @Lahiru-Jayasundara Please accept if it solved your question. Thank you.